# I want to not close the modal during API communication

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am using bootstrap-vue.

Input in the displayed modal and let the API communicate.
One way I thought was to use spinner-overlay to keep the modal closed while communicating.
https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/overlay#overlay

I tried to make the code below, but the Spinner is displayed under the modal.
How can I display Spinner so that it doesn't keep the modal closed?

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-overlay :show="show" blur="none" rounded="sm">
      <b-modal
        id="modal-prevent-closing"
        ref="modal"
        title="Change Modal"
        @show="showInit"
        @hidden="resetModal"
        @ok="handleOk"
      >
        <table class="table table-striped">
          <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
              <th scope="col"></th>
              <th scope="col">Old Name</th>
              <th scope="col">New Name</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <draggable
            v-model="tableData"
            :options="{ handle: '.item-handle' }"
            tag="tbody"
          >
            <tr v-for="item in tableData" :key="item.name">
              <td scope="row"><span class="item-handle">::</span></td>
              <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
              <td><b-form-input type="text" v-model="item.newName" /></td>
            </tr>
          </draggable>
        </table>
        <!-- I want to overlay the entire screen -->
        <b-button :disabled="show" variant="primary" @click="show = true">
          Test Show overlay
        </b-button>
      </b-modal>
    </b-overlay>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import draggable from "vuedraggable";
export default {
  props: {
    requrl: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    items: Array,
  },
  components: {
    draggable,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      initTableData: [],
      tableData: [],
      // overlay
      show: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    showInit() {
      ...
    },
    resetModal() {
      ...
    },
    handleOk(bvModalEvt) {
      // Prevent modal from closing
      bvModalEvt.preventDefault();
      ...
    },
    handleSubmit() {
        ...
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

---

Use

- "bootstrap-vue": "^2.16.0",
- "vue": "^2.6.11",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue is that `<b-modal>` is appended to the bottom of `<body>` by default. So it's actually getting move out of your `<b-overlay>`, and the `z-index` of `<b-overlay>` is 10 by default while the modal has 1050.

To get around all these issues, you can add `no-wrap` and `fixed` to `<b-overlay>` which will make it cover the entire screen, along with `z-index="1100"` which should put the overlay above your modal.

You also need to move `<b-modal>` outside of `<b-overlay>` as the default slot is ignored when the `no-wrap` prop is added.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      isBusy: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onOk(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      if (!this.isBusy) {
        this.isBusy = true;

        // Mock API call
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.$bvModal.hide('my-modal')
          this.isBusy = false;
        }, 2500)
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.16.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.16.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <b-btn v-b-modal.my-modal>Open Modal</b-btn>

  <b-overlay :show="isBusy" no-wrap fixed z-index="1100"></b-overlay>
  <b-modal id="my-modal" @ok="onOk">
    Click OK to call API
  </b-modal>
</div>
```